# How to dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 after installing ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot

I am using Ubuntu as my only operating system , now I want to dual boot with windows 10

Comment: UEFI or BIOS only hardware? UEFI or BIOS install of Ubuntu? Is drive gpt or MBR? Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt and only in BIOS mode to MBR(msdos). If one drive, both must be installed in same boot mode. And most hardware now is UEFI.

Comment: If making the Windows 10 installer USB from Ubuntu will need to use woeusb or mkusb programs so windows boots from USB.

Comment: Will you be gaming on the Windows 10 install?